# What's convergence in a group look like?

Tags: sequences-and-series, group-theory, convergence-divergence

How should we define convergence for sequences and series in groups?

Here's maybe how to do it:

Let $G$ be a group.  A norm will be like a norm defined on a vector space except we'll define it with multiplicative notation.  Let $|\cdot| \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Be a norm on a group $G$.  It should satisfy:
$$
\begin{align*}
    &(1) \ |ab| \leq |a| + |b| \\
    &(2) \ |a| = 0 \implies a = 1
\end{align*}
$$

Then a sequence $(a_i) \subset G$ will converge under the norm to $a$ iff for all $\epsilon \gt 1$ there's $N$ such that for all $n \gt N$, $ \ |a_ia^{-1}| \lt \epsilon$.

Comment: Your question contains an answer, but it does not seem to contain a question.

Comment: So you are asking what convergence in an abstract group may look like. What is your motivation for looking at convergence, as this may determine how best to define it.

Comment: I want permutations of the naturals to be limits of series of transpositions (or something like that).

Comment: To define convergence you do not need norm/metric, it suffices to have a topology. The notion of a topological group can be found herehttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_group On the other hand, I am not sure what kind of series you have in mind, since general groups are noncommutative. You can use infinite products in topological groups and define convergence the same way you do it for series.

Comment: Do you know what a Cayley graph is? You can use this to define a metric on your group (which is dependent on your generating set). See my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469068/metric-property-in-a-group/469084#469084). This "word metric" is an important tool in geometric group theory, especially in the theory of hyperbolic groups where limits of this metric are studied (the key word is the *boundary* of a hyperbolic group).